# Recursive function returns undefined regardless of enough return statements

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have read a few questions and answers on it already. It looks like my recursive function has got enough "return" statements, so... I do not know why it returns undefined... I have added extra log statement to show that the function itself finds the element, but does not return it...

```js
let animals = [
  {
    name: "dogs",
    id: 1,
    children: [
      {
        name: "lessie",
        id: 2
      },
      {
        name: "bark-a-lot",
        id: 3
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "cats",
    id: 4,
    children: [
      {
        name: "meows-a-lot",
        id: 5,
        children: [
          {
            name: "meows-a-lot-in-the-morning",
            id: 6
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "whisk-ass",
        id: 7
      }
    ]
  }
];

function recurseFind(node, id) {
  if (Array.isArray(node)) {
    return node.forEach(el => {
      return recurseFind(el, id);
    });
  } else {
    if (node.id === id) {
      console.log("node matched", node.id, id, node);
      return node;
    } else if (node.children) {
      return node.children.forEach(child => {
        return recurseFind(child, id);
      });
    } else {
      return "not found";
    }
  }
}

const found = recurseFind(animals, 6);
console.log("found", found, "wtf");
```

Comment: `return node.forEach()` - there is your problem, `forEach` always returns `undefined`. You probably meant to use `.map` or `.find` (for many results or one)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`forEach` returns `undefined`, so

```
return node.forEach(el => {
  return recurseFind(el, id);
});
```

will always return `undefined`, no matter what the recursive calls find.

I'd use a `for` loop instead, and if a match is found, return it:

```js
let animals = [
  {
    name: "dogs",
    id: 1,
    children: [
      {
        name: "lessie",
        id: 2
      },
      {
        name: "bark-a-lot",
        id: 3
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "cats",
    id: 4,
    children: [
      {
        name: "meows-a-lot",
        id: 5,
        children: [
          {
            name: "meows-a-lot-in-the-morning",
            id: 6
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "whisk-ass",
        id: 7
      }
    ]
  }
];

function recurseFind(node, id) {
  if (Array.isArray(node)) {
    for (const el of node) {
      const result = recurseFind(el, id);
      if (result) return result;
    }
  } else {
    if (node.id === id) {
      return node;
    } else if (node.children) {
      for (const child of node.children) {
        const result = recurseFind(child, id);
        if (result) return result;
      }
    }
  }
}

const found = recurseFind(animals, 6) || 'not found';
console.log("found", found);
```

Answer (score 1):

VLAZ and CertainPerformance already pointed out why your function wasn't working.

Here's an alternative technique that seems a little simpler to me:

```js
const recursiveFind = (pred) => (xs) => xs .reduce (
  (r, x) => r != null ? r : pred (x) ? x : recursiveFind (pred) (x.children || []) || null,
  null
)

const findById = (id) => recursiveFind(x => x.id == id)

const animals = [{name: "dogs", id: 1, children: [{name: "lessie", id: 2}, {name: "bark-a-lot", id: 3}]}, {name: "cats", id: 4, children: [{name: "meows-a-lot", id: 5, children: [{ name: "meows-a-lot-in-the-morning", id: 6}]}, {name: "whisk-ass", id: 7}]}];

console .log (findById (3) (animals))
console .log (findById (4) (animals))
```

We start with a generic function that searches for objects nested this way by whether they match the supplied predicate function.  Then we pass it the predicate `x => x.id == id` to create a function that takes an id and then a list of values and finds the first value with matching ids  in the list, or `null` if none are found.

If you have absolutely no use for this `recursiveFind` function, you can inline it into `findById` like this:

```js
const findById = (id, xs) => xs .reduce (
  (r, x) => r != null ? r : x.id == id ? x : findById (id, x.children || []) || null,
  null
)

findById (3, animals)
```

But I actually would prefer to go in the other direction, and make it still more generic, using something like this:

```js
const recursiveFind = (pred, descend) => (xs) => xs .reduce (
  (r, x) => r != null ? r :  pred (x) ? x : recursiveFind (pred, descend) (descend (x) || []) || null,
  null
)

const findById = (id) => recursiveFind (x => x.id == id, x => x.children)

findById (3) (animals)
```

This version also parameterizes how we descend into the children of a node.  In this case, we simply use `x => x.children`, but it's easy to imagine using other properties or a more complex method.

In all of these, do note that the function processes all nodes of your nested array structure, even when we've already found a match.  If we have, the first check (`r != null`) skips ahead quickly, but if performance is critical, you might prefer a solution with explicit short-circuiting loops such as the one from CertainPerformance.