# Moving an object in a recursive array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, sorting, recursion

I am working on a vue js app and i have the following recursive array :

```
[
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "sam",
            list: [
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: "john",
                    list: []
                },
                {
                    id: 6,
                    name: "sarah",
                    list: [
                        {
                            id: 21,
                            name: "fadi",
                            list: []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: "ross",
            list: [
                {
                    id: 4,
                    name: "maya",
                    list: []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 5,
            name: "steph",
            list: []
        },
        {
            id: 7,
            name: "joseph",
            list: []
        },
    ],
```

So i have the id of the object that needs moving and the id of where it should be moved for example i get idmoving=6 and destination = 2 so the object of id 6 with its content should move to the list of the object of id 2 the list becomes the following:

```
    [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "sam",
            list: [
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: "john",
                    list: [
                {
                    id: 6,
                    name: "sarah",
                    list: [
                        {
                            id: 21,
                            name: "fadi",
                            list: []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: "ross",
            list: [
                {
                    id: 4,
                    name: "maya",
                    list: []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 5,
            name: "steph",
            list: []
        },
        {
            id: 7,
            name: "joseph",
            list: []
        },
    ],
```

I'm sorry i'm still new to this i hope someone can help with a function that can do that.

Answer (score 3):

You could get the source array and index of the wanted node and the target object in advance and splice the array and push the spliced array to the target array.

This approach takes a depth first search and exit the recursion if both nodes are found.

```js
const
    move = (data, from, to) => {
        const
            search = array => array.some((o, index) => {
                if (o.id === from) source = { array, index };
                else if (o.id === to) target = o;
                return source && target || search(o.list);
            });
        let source, target;

        if (!search(data)) return;
        target.list.push(...source.array.splice(source.index, 1));
    },
    data = [{ id: 1, name: "sam", list: [{ id: 2, name: "john", list: [] }, { id: 6, name: "sarah", list: [{ id: 21, name: "fadi", list: [] }] }] }, { id: 3, name: "ross", list: [{ id: 4, name: "maya", list: [] }] }, { id: 5, name: "steph", list: [] }, { id: 7, name: "joseph", list: [] }];

move(data, 6, 2);
       
console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: this is imperative form at its very finest. a true inspiration, nina

Answer (score 3):

I would probably write this atop some reusable helper functions.  Moving a value is a matter of finding it in one location, removing it from there, and adding it to a new location.  So I would write a `move` function that uses `find`, `remove`, and `add` functions.

Each can be done with some fairly simple recursion.  Here's one approach:

```js
// Helper functions
const findById = (id, xs) => 
  xs .reduce (
    (r, x) => r != null ? r : x.id == id ? x : findById (id, x .list) || null,
    null
  )

const removeById = (id, xs) =>
  xs .reduce (
    (r, x) => x.id === id ? r : [... r, {... x, list: removeById (id, x .list)}], 
    [] 
  )

const addById = (id, newVal, xs) =>
  xs .reduce (
    (r, x) => [... r, {... x, list: [... addById (id, newVal, x .list), ... (x.id == id ? [newVal] : [])]}],
    []
  )

// Main function
const moveById = (id, toId, data) => 
  addById (toId, findById (id, data), removeById (id, data))


// Sample data
const data = 
  [{id: 1, list: [{id: 2, list: [], name: "john"}, {id: 6, list: [{id: 21, list: [], name: "fadi"}], name: "sarah"}], name: "sam"}, {id: 3, list: [{id: 4, list: [], name: "maya"}], name: "ross"}, {id: 5, list: [], name: "steph"}, {id: 7, list: [], name: "joseph"}]

// Demo
console .log (moveById (6, 2, data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top : 0}
```

This is not complete.  Presumably, there needs to be some sort of error-checking about whether a value has been found before we try to add it.

I would actually write these helpers in a more generic fashion, using an arbitrary predicate for input rather than an id.  If they were curried, then we could easily create `findById` by passing the result of applying an id value to a function like `(id) => (x) => x.id == id` to create a predicate.  So in practice, I might write something more like:

```js
const recursiveFind = (pred) => (xs) => 
  xs .reduce (
    (r, x) => r != null ? r : pred (x) ? x : recursiveFind (pred) (x .list || []) || null,
    null
  )

const findById = (id) => 
  recursiveFind (x => x.id === id)
```

And something similar for `remove` and `add`.

These become useful with, say, `recursiveRemove ((x) => x.id > 5) (data)`, which would remove all elements at any level of nesting with ids greater than 5.

And I might go still further to make your `list` property parameterizable.  But you can see that approach in [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60838654).

Comment: Instead of one behemoth function, we get four smaller reusable ones :D

Comment: How would you write the **removeById** , **addById** and **moveById** in a more generic way? @Scott Sauyet